# BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray returns null

Tags: android, base64

Looks good?

```java
public static Bitmap stringToImage(String base64) {

    byte[] decodedString = decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
}
```

this code returns null, if my base64 string starts with "data:image/jpeg;base64,". but if I remov this prefix - this code works fine! How to solve this problem?

I tested my base64 string and it works fine (comment 1 [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/display-base64-image-in-html))

Comment: I can to remove this prefix manually, but whether there is a class/method that will automatically remove it?

Comment: using the regexp - Pattern.compile("^(data:image/.+;base64,).+");
Android does not contains a mime-type strip method :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u may use before passing the String to function

```
    String base64="";
base64.replaceAll("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
```

pls change given string according to ur string

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm confused, "data:image/jpeg;base64," is not a valid part of a base64 string. If that's the case, it's really no wonder it's not decoding correctly. Just remove it from the head of the string before you decode if it's causing problems.